# Sorting a Pandas series in ascending order after using the sort_values() function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I wrote a code to get the count of values in a Pandas column:

```
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Workstation/Downloads/Grades_Dataset.xlsx")

Science = df['Science(Mid-term)']
counts = Science.value_counts()
```

When I print it, I get this output:

```
45.0     178
75.0      72
98.0      72
65.0      72
89.0      70
55.0      70
49.0      36
100.0     36
48.0      36
86.0      36
32.0      36
44.0      35
94.0      35
78.0      35
33.0      35
88.0      35
61.0      35
74.0      35
68.0      35
58.0      35
```

Is there a way to sort this by the first column (i.e. 0 = 23; 1 = 26, 2 = 65 e.t.c)?

I want to plot the data to show the number of students who received a particular mark. But becuase of the order the plotting output is:

[image]

The code for the plot:

```
plt.plot(counts)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you want this: `Science.value_counts().sort_index()`. The "first" column is, at really, an index.

Comment: Thanks @igorkf it worked.

Comment: Just a follow up question, how can I plot a scatterplot with this data? It needs an X and Y axis. Thanks,

Comment: I don't know your column names, even your dataframe structure, but maybe this works: `df.value_counts().to_frame().reset_index().plot.scatter(x='a', y='b');`

Comment: Thanks, I'll surely try it!